# How do you simplify $\tan 10A$ in terms of $5A$?

Tags: trigonometry

How do you simplify $\tan 10A$ in terms of $5A$?

I just need a few steps to get me going. All help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: it would be quite messy to write everything in term of $\tan A$, if that is what you are after. otherwise what does it mean to simplify it.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about what you mean by 'simple': $\tan 10A$ looks fairly simple already!

Comment: Oh sorry, again. I'm solving for tan5A :D

Comment: The question states:

"Simplify each of the following in terms of the indicated angle:
tan 10A; 5A"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $\theta=5A$, so that $10A=2\theta$. Thus, your goal is to express $\tan(2\theta)$ in terms of $\theta$ (and then you can plug $5A$ back in for $\theta$ when you're done). Do you know the double-angle formula for tangent? If not, remember that
$$\tan(2\theta)=\frac{\sin(2\theta)}{\cos(2\theta)},$$
and then apply the double-angle formula for sine and cosine. If you *then* want this result in terms of $\tan(\theta)$, you can divide the numerator and denominator by an appropriately chosen quantity.

Answer (score 0):

Using [de Moivre's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula),
$$\cos 10x+i\sin 10x=(\cos x+i\sin x)^{10}$$
$$=\sum_{0\le r\le 10}\binom {10}r(\cos x)^{10-r}(i\sin x)^r$$

$$=\sum_{0\le 2s+1\le 10}\binom {10}{2s}(\cos x)^{10-2s}(i\sin x)^{2s}+\binom {10}{2s+1}(\cos x)^{2n-2s-1}(i\sin x)^{2s+1}$$

$$=\sum_{0\le 2s+1\le 10}\binom {10}{2s}(\cos x)^{10-2s}(\sin x)^{2s}(-1)^s+i\binom {10}{2s+1}(\cos x)^{2n-2s-1}(\sin x)^{2s+1}(-1)^s$$

Equating the real & the imaginary parts,

$$\cos10x=\sum_{0\le 2s+1\le 10}\binom {10}{2s}(\cos x)^{10-2s}(\sin x)^{2s}(-1)^s$$
$$=(\cos x)^{10}-\binom {10}2(\cos x)^8(\sin x)^{2}+\binom {10}4(\cos x)^6(\sin x)^4-\binom {10}6(\cos x)^4(\sin x)^6+\binom {10}8(\cos x)^2(\sin x)^8-(\sin x)^{10}$$
$$=(\cos x)^{10}\{1-(\tan x)^{2}+\binom {10}4 (\tan x)^4-\binom {10}6 (\tan x)^6+\binom {10}8 (\tan x)^8-(\tan x)^{10}\}$$

Simailrly, 
$$\sin10x=(\cos x)^{10}\{\binom {10}1 (\tan x)-\binom {10}3 (\tan x)^3+\binom {10}5 (\tan x)^5-\binom {10}7 (\tan x)^7+\binom {10}9 (\tan x)^9\}$$

Divide to get $\tan10x$ in terms of $\tan x$

Validate [here](http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/trigonometry/multipleAnglesTangent.htm).